# How to use multiple references in Gerrit Access Control

Tags: git, gerrit

Am trying to setup Access Control for a project (repository) in Gerrit.

I want to give the same permissions for a group of users to multiple references so am using the regular expression

```
^refs/heads/(dev-a|dev-b|dev-b).*
```

But it fails and doesnt allow the users/groups under this reference to submit/label/do any other operation listed
If i declare the references individually like below it allows.

```
refs/heads/dev-a
```

so i suspect if my regular expression is wrong. Can some one help me?

Answer (score -1):

In documentation they stated that Gerrit uses dk.brics.automaton library for evaluation of regular expression access control rules.

So here is doc for that:
http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html?dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html

Comment: @paper1111: The answer is phrased as a question, but it could be recast as "Don't use dashes". Answers that are guesswork with some references for backing can be downvoted, but they certainly are legitimate answers and should not be flagged or deleted. (Even a baseless guess should generally not be deleted.)

Comment: I couldn't add comment to question. I couldn't test it in my gerrit.